http request conversion from php to node
Im passing legacy php server to node. i have this php guzzle http request to some dashboard:

 $request = $this->http_client->request('POST',
      $url,
      [ 'headers' => ['Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
        'form_params' => [
        'authenticity_token'=> $authKey,
        'affiliate_user_session[login]'=>$this->partner->username,
        'affiliate_user_session[password]'=>$this->partner->password,
        'commit'=>'Log In to Portal'
        ]
      ]
    );

it works correctly and i got back my response data.
but when Im trying to do same request in my node server i got error 422 -  Unprocessable Entity, which as i understand imply that there is some syntactic error in the request.
the code in node axios:
const postResponse = await axios.post(
                url,
                {
                    'authenticity_token': authKey,
                    'affiliate_user_session[login]': name,
                    'affiliate_user_session[password]': password,
                    'commit': 'Log In to Portal',
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }
                }
            );



the key, username, and password are the same.
so what is that syntactic error?
I got the same error when Im sending this request from postman.

First guess would be that both perhaps handle the URL encoding (or lack thereof) of [ and ] inside the parameter names differently. Try and specify them as affiliate_user_session%5Blogin%5D and affiliate_user_session%5Bpassword%5D in your axios attempt, and see if that changes anything.

Axios and Guzzle seem to handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded data differently.

In PHP with Guzzle, the form_params option automatically converts the
data into a query-string format, which is what the server expects
when the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

In Axios, you're sending the data as a JSON object, which isn't
properly encoded. You need to encode the data in
query-string format when using Axios.


You can use the URLSearchParams API for this, try something like this:
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('authenticity_token', authKey);
params.append('affiliate_user_session[login]', name);
params.append('affiliate_user_session[password]', password);
params.append('commit', 'Log In to Portal');

const postResponse = await axios.post(
    url,
    params.toString(), 
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    }
);

You can read more about that approach here. There it is also mentioned that "alternatively, you can encode data using the qs library"

i try both the approaches (separate, and together), changing the params to be new URLSearchParams(), adding toString(), and tried to change the  brackets to %5B / %5D but still get error 422.  What else can i try to do to solve this?

it seems like the php code using [] array to pass the params. Maybe I need to do it as well in node?

try to look at the params that get created and output them to the console. Then post the result here to see if you formatted it correctly. Alternatively, you can use the qs library:
const qs = require('qs');
const data = qs.stringify({
'authenticity_token': authKey,
'affiliate_user_session[login]': name,
'affiliate_user_session[password]': password,
'commit': 'Log In to Portal',
});
const postResponse = await axios.post(
url,
data,
{
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
}
)

So the problem was that in PHP, the Guzzle client manages cookies automatically, which is not the case with Axios in JavaScript. The solution was to manually extract the cookie from the dashboard response and attach it to the headers of my subsequent requests to the dashboard.
